# use distinct and order by in STRING_AGG function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying the string_agg a column while at the same time ordering the column and only show unique values. Consider the following demo. IS there a syntax issue or is this simply not possible with the method I am using?

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT foo.a::TEXT,',' ORDER BY foo.a DESC)
              FROM (
                       SELECT 1 As a
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT 1
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT 1
                       UNION ALL
                       SELECT 2
                   ) AS foo
```

> [2019-11-22 13:29:32] [42P10] ERROR: in an aggregate with DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in argument list
>   [2019-11-22 13:29:32] Position: 53

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. The expression that you use in the `ORDER BY` clause must also appear in the aggregated part.

You could do:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT foo.a::TEXT, ',' ORDER BY foo.a::TEXT DESC)
FROM (
    SELECT 1 As a
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
) AS foo
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=19334096821ccffb0c5abe23b535352c)**

While this will work, the problem with this solution is that it will order numbers as strings, that do not have the same ordering rules. String wise, `10` is less than `2`.

Another option is to use arrays: first, `ARRAY_AGG()` can be used to aggregate the numbers (with proper, numeric ordering), then you can turn it to a comma-separated list of strings with `ARRAY_TO_STRING()`.

```
SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT a ORDER BY a DESC), ',')
FROM (
    SELECT 1 As a
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 2
) AS foo
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=10bba3702799c1c6aaff19384c83d679)**